# How to automatically delete mail from specific sender?

Tags: mail.app, email, automator

I'm in the mail app on mac and I'm clearing out my Gmail archives and trying to speed up the process by finding senders, i.e. "verify@twitter.com" or any of the promotional ones that they send weekly stuff, etc.

Then pasting their addresses in the search and deleting all the mail from it at once. I feel like there must be a way to automate this using Automator, but when looking at the program I can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I usually sort by sender and then select/delete huge blocks at once. Even with Automator you would need to identify the sender addresses first, this might take more time than the actual deletion step.

Comment: What you can use automator for is to make a list of all senders sorted by domain. Then just copy pasta in Search bar(or in the rule set for deletion) and delete key(or apply the rule). Later empty trash.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need Automator for this.

- Open your Gmail account in Mail
- Create a mail rule for that account which deletes messages from the senders you want to get rid of
- When saving the rule, you will be asked whether you want to apply the rule to the mails in the current mailbox

Comment: @NourMakarem Great! Welcome to Ask Different, actually, please have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and the other pages in the help center to learn more about how the site works.

Comment: I highly recommend creating rules that move emails to the rubbish and not permanently delete in case you accidentally lose an important email. (For example, the twitter email you mentioned in your question is used for security purposes such as password resets!)